# Regular expression which matches a String also containing brackets

Tags: java, regex

I have the following text

```
bla bla ==   aaaaaa(bb)aaaaaa  == bla bla
```

I would like to find the String (Match)

```
==   aaaaaa(bb)aaaaaa   ==
```

I do not know how many spaces are between the == and the aaaaaa are, so the text could also be

```
bla bla ==          aaaaaa(bb)aaaaaa  == bla bla
```

in that case I would like to match

```
==          aaaaaa(bb)aaaaaa  ==
```

I tried with following regex, but I realize that the brackets are not recognized:

```
==(.+?)aaaaaa(bb)aaaaaa(.+?)==
```

Howto do ?

Comment: Are `(` and `)` special characters in a regular expression? What do you do with special characters?

Comment: You should use `== +aaaaaa\\(bb\\)aaaaaa +==`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match `(` and `)` in your string, you need to put backslash characters before them.  I think you probably want something like

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("==(.+?)aaaaaa\\(bb\\)aaaaaa(.+?)==");
```

(You need to include the backslash twice in a string literal in order to get one backslash into the actual pattern.)

Comment: Additional question: What characters have to be escaped in a regex like my ( and )

Comment: @user1344545 (1) See the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).  (2) If you're not sure, you can escape any character that isn't alphabetic.  (3) Look at the `quote()` method in `Pattern`, which will automatically escape characters that need it.

Answer (score 2):

Put a backslash before the `(` and `)` to use them as regular characters, this must work:

```
==(.+?)aaaaaa\(bb\)aaaaaa(.+?)==
```

Comment: Thank you are right. I searched for the java string, thats why I accepted for ajb. I answered yours as usefull :-)